# When is the 'Reviews' tab under 'Activity' in a user's profile updated? What activity does it track?

Tags: support, profile-page

What information is tracked under the *Reviews* tab in the *Activity* section of a user's profile?

---

[image: edited screenshot of section referred to]

---

I assume this section is related in some way to actions which are performed on [**posts listed for review**](https://askubuntu.com/review/). But I thought that I had reviewed some posts which were in this list, yet nothing has changed under [***Reviews* in my profile**](https://askubuntu.com/users/52923/irrational-john?tab=activity&sort=reviews).

I clearly do not understand the *Reviews* tab or the information it is meant to provide.

---

#### I think I understand now

If you *suggest* an edit then this is tracked under the *Suggestions* tab in the *Activity* section. If you review a suggested edit and either approve or reject it, then this is (apparently) tracked under the *Reviews* tab.

Since I lack the karma to do any approving or rejecting, there is not going to be any activity under my *Reviews* tab.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's related to suggested edits.

For an example, take a look at [my review tab](https://askubuntu.com/users/6005/jrg?tab=activity&sort=reviews).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Also check this blogpost:

- http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/11/improved-reviewing/

To see how you can track your review progress!